# How to set up automatic SSH tunnel

Tags: ssh, openssh, ssh-tunnel

I've been using SSH's remote forwarding feature to forward connections to 
a Unix domain socket on a remote host `example.com` to a Unix domain socket 
on my local machine. Both machines run Linux. The command is the following:

`ssh -N -n -R /home/guest/daemon.sock:/var/run/daemon.sock guest@example.com`

I want to automate this so the tunnel gets created automatically every time
my machine boots up.  I've copied the file `/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub`
from my local machine into the remote's `/home/guest/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`, and 
appended the following lines to `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` on my local machine:

`Host example.com
  User guest
  IdentityFile /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
  RemoteForward /home/guest/daemon.sock /var/run/daemon.sock`

For security reasons, I also want to restrict user 'guest' on the remote
machine to tunnel creation and nothing else. I've therefore appended the
following lines to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on the remote host:

`match User guest
  AllowTcpForwarding yes
  X11Forwarding no
  AllowAgentForwarding no
  ForceCommand /bin/false`

Here's the problem: nothing happens when my local machine boots up.
I'm sure I'm missing something important, but couldn't find what.
Any ideas?

Comment: There is a part missing from the question where you describe how you instigate the connection on boot - or are you expecting the above to do it?  Note that your public key appends to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the remote

Comment: You might look at `stunnel` and `vtun`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ssh_config` file does absolutely nothing to automate SSH connections.

It only exists to allow defining the **default options** – whenever you run `ssh example.com`, then the corresponding "Host" section is looked up and all options added to the command line. (You could say it's similar to shell aliases.) The per-user `~/.ssh/config` is more commonly used for the same purpose.

But it still remains up to you to actually *run* the `ssh` command, e.g. through a systemd .service unit, or an /etc/init.d script, or a cron job. (Don't forget to define in the service that it needs to start after networking has been configured.)

(You *may* continue using ssh_config, but it is useless here and will only make *regular* connections to `example.com` annoying. Just specify the same options directly in the service file instead.)

---

While not illegal, it is somewhat weird to reuse the host key for client-side authentication. It would be better to generate a dedicated keypair using `ssh-keygen`.

And as @Paul noted in the comment, trusted keys must be listed in `authorized_keys` – the SSH server does not care about any of the `id_*` files.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I was under the misguided impression that `ssh_config` would automatically setup a connection when the SSH service started. Anyway, I'll create a Systemd service for this...